# How to export org-mode to ODT with endnotes?

Tags: org-export, odt

If an org-mode document includes footnotes, and you export to ODT, you get footnotes at the bottom of every page.

For a journal submission, I need these to be endnotes.

This is fairly easy in LaTeX export, but I can't find the switch for ODT export. I did find that I can manually edit the ODT in LibreOffice to move footnotes to "end of document," so I think I can do what I need by hand. But... would be nice if it could "just work."

Answer (score 1):

> If an org-mode document includes footnotes, and you export to ODT, you get footnotes at the bottom of every page.

There are two ways to achieve this:

#### Snippet 1: Use footnotes on OpenDocument side, but use custom styles to place the footnotes at the end of the document.

```
#+odt_extra_styles: <text:notes-configuration
#+odt_extra_styles:     text:note-class="footnote"
#+odt_extra_styles:     text:default-style-name="Footnote"
#+odt_extra_styles:     text:citation-style-name="Footnote_20_Symbol"
#+odt_extra_styles:     text:citation-body-style-name="Footnote_20_anchor"
#+odt_extra_styles:     text:master-page-name="Footnote" style:num-format="1"
#+odt_extra_styles:     text:start-value="0" text:footnotes-position="document"
#+odt_extra_styles:     text:start-numbering-at="document"/>

Body text[fn:1][fn:2]

* Footnotes

[fn:1] Footnote one
[fn:2] Footnote two
```

#### Snippet 2: Use actual endnotes on OpenDocument side

```
#+odt_endnote_regexp: .

Body text[fn:1][fn:2]

* Footnotes

[fn:1] Footnote one
[fn:2] Footnote two
```

The difference between the two snippets is this:

1. In the first snippet, an org-side footnote is mapped to a `footnote' note-class on OpenDocument side.
2. In the second snippet, an org-side footnote is mapped to a `endnote' note-cass on OpeDocument side.

For more information see [Add support for endnotes · Issue #74](https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt/issues/74)

Note that this feature is exclusive to the [**fork** of OpenDocument exporter](https://kjambunathan.gitlab.io/org-mode-ox-odt/Getting-Started-with-ODT-export.html#Installation), i.e. this feature is **NOT** available in the standard Emacs or Org mode repositories.